# My blog posts section seems to be rendering the other blog posts inside the first? :/

Tags: php, posts

After a recent Wordpress update, my blog page seems to be rendering the 1st post with all the other posts rendered within the same div. It was working before but since the update, this and the pagination doesn't seem to be working :/

main template file

```
<div class="section">
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <?php if( get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == 'right-sidebar' || get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == '') { ?>
                <div class="col-md-9 right-sidebar-class">
                <?php } elseif( get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == 'left-sidebar') { ?>
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-9 left-sidebar-class">
                <?php } elseif( get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == 'full-width') { ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12 full-width-index">
                <?php } ?>
                    <div class="widget-blog-list">
                        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                                <?php get_template_part( 'post-format/content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                            <?php endwhile; ?>
                            <div>
                            <?php the_posts_pagination( array(
                                    'mid_size' => 2,
                                    'prev_text'          => esc_html__( 'Previous page', '' ),
                                    'next_text'          => esc_html__( 'Next page', '' ),
                                    'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text"></span>',
                                ) ); ?>
                            </div>

                        <?php else : ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    </div>
                </div>


                <?php if( get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == 'right-sidebar' || get_option_tree( 'bloglayout' ) == '') { ?>
                    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

post-format/content file

```
<?php 
    if ( ! is_single() ) : 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ot_get_option('post_format_type_1') == 'on') : 
?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('blog-item'); ?>>
<?php else : ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('blog-item no-left-content'); ?>style="width:400px">
<?php 
    endif;  
    endif; 
?>


<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
    $att=get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'span5' );
    $image_src = $image_src[0]; 
?>

<?php if ( ot_get_option('post_format_type_2') != 'on' || ot_get_option('post_format_type_1') != 'off' ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_src); ?>"/></a>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( ot_get_option('post_format_type_2') == 'on' || ot_get_option('post_format_type_1') == 'on' ) : ?>
        <div class="item-media">
            <div class="media-photo">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" data-background="<?php echo esc_url($image_src); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo esc_url($image_src); ?>);"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( ! is_single() ) : ?>
    <div class="item-desc">
        <?php
            if ( ! is_single() ) :
                the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title all-caps"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' );
            endif;
        ?>
        <h5><?php esc_html_e('BY', ''); ?> <a class="uppercase" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></a>  <?php the_tags( '', ',', ' '); ?></h5>
        <?php
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
        /*  the_content( sprintf( */
        /*      esc_html__( 'Continue reading %s', '' ),  */
        /*      the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )  */
        /*  ) );  */
        /*  
        /*  NEW CONTENT   */
 $content = get_the_content(); echo mb_strimwidth($content, 0, 220, '...');

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', '' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
                'pagelink'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Page', '' ) . ' </span>%',
                'separator'   => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>

 <!-- Single Detail -->
    <div class="single-detail">
        <div class="detail-head">
            <?php esc_html_e('BY', ''); ?> <a class="uppercase" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></a> <?php the_tags( '', ',', ' '); ?> <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i> <a class="uppercase"href="<?php comments_link(); ?> "><?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="detail-content">
            <?php
                /* translators: %s: Name of current post */
                the_content( sprintf(
                    esc_html__( 'Continue reading %s', '' ),
                    the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
                ) );

                wp_link_pages( array(
                    'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', '' ) . '</span>',
                    'after'       => '</div>',
                    'link_before' => '<span>',
                    'link_after'  => '</span>',
                    'pagelink'    => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html__( 'Page', '' ) . ' </span>%',
                    'separator'   => '<span class="screen-reader-text">, </span>',
                ) );
            ?>
        </div>

        <div class="detail-tags">
            <h5><?php esc_html_e( 'TAGS', ''); ?></h5>
                <?php the_tags( '<ul><li>', '</li><li>', '</li></ul>' ); ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- Single Detail End -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

The is a screen shot of the blog content section

[image: Screenshot of Html]

Comment: Which `div` element is enclosing all of the repeated posts?

Comment: I've added in a screenshot of the html elements, notice how the 1st post contains the other posts?

Comment: Try looking at the page source instead of at a page inspector's view.  Browswers like Chrome and FF will try to close tags and fix some markup issues automatically.  Looking at the unaltered source, I expect you will find a syntax problem, like an unclosed or mismatched `div` element closing tag.

Comment: You might also find simplifying the templates helpful in finding the problem.  Temporarily removing the conditional statements and working down one path at a time until you find the problem.  It certainly looks like the initial `<div id="post...` element is not closed before the loop repeats but I'm not seeing the problem glancing at your code.